# Is there a way to express the block matrix with 1 in the position (i,j) of the block [i,j] and 0 otherwise in some compact form?

Tags: block-matrices, kronecker-product

$\delta_{[i,j]}$ is defined as the $N^2\times N^2$ block matrix whose elements $(i,j)$ in the block $[i,j]$ are equal to 1, and all the others are 0.

I'm looking for a way to express it as a function of appropriates $N\times N$ matrices, for example as a kronecker product or sum.

Comment: Why not just define a matrix $B_{ij}$ to be the matrix you want?

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\e{{\bf e}}
\def\B{{\bf B}}
\def\E{{\bf E}}
\def\J{{\bf J}}
\def\n{\nabla}\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$Let $I\in\bbR{n\times n}$ denote the *identity* matrix and let $\e_k$ denote its $k^{th}$ column vector.

The $\e_k$ vectors are the standard vector basis for $\bbR{n}.\:$ Using the $\e_k$ vectors, an arbitrary matrix $A\in\bbR{n\times n}$ can be decomposed into its constituent scalar elements
$$\eqalign{
A_{kl} &= \e_k^TA\e_l \qif
 A = \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^n \e_kA_{kl}\e_l^T \\
}$$
Block-analogs of the $\e_k$ vectors can be constructed using the Kronecker product
$$\eqalign{
\E_k &= \e_k\otimes I \\
}$$
It should come as no surprise that the $\E_k$ matrices can be used to decompose a block matrix $\B\in\bbR{n^2\times n^2}$ into its constituent blocks $B_{kl}\in\bbR{n\times n}$
$$\eqalign{
B_{kl} &= \E_k^T\B\E_l \qif \B = \sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^n \E_kB_{kl}\E_l^T \\
}$$
Let $J\in\bbR{n\times n}$ denote the *all-ones* matrix. Then setting $B_{ij}=J$ and all other $B_{kl}=0$, the summation reduces to a single non-zero term and the desired block matrix is
$${\E_i J \E_j^T}$$

Comment: I think there is a confusion with the notation of my question. With [ ]  I represent block indices, while with ( ) I represent indices inside the blocks. In your notation, $(\delta_{ij})_{ij}=1$ and  $(\delta_{ij})_{uv}=0$ for all $u\neq i$ and $v\neq j$ for each block. Each block  has non-zero entry in the same position of the block.

Comment: So it sounds like you want
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^n \E_k\e_k\e_l^T\E_l^T$$

Comment: Exactly! Thanks